# Forward Declaration Assignment Help C++

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I would like some help on forward declaration because I'm not that familiar with it. When I was assigning an instance of the main class (HelloWorld) to a local HelloWorld* variable in my Background class. It crashes. While the **parent** variable evaluates to not null, it crashes upon checking/validating **m_Parent**. Can someone explain why it is crashing because there's no error message at all when I try to debug it in the console.

.h file

```
#ifndef _Background_
#define _Background_

class HelloWorld;
class Background
{

public:
    void init(HelloWorld* const & parent);
private:
     Background();
    ~Background();
    HelloWorld* m_Parent;
};
#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"

void Background::init(HelloWorld* const & parent)
{
    m_Parent = parent;
}
```

Comment: Forward declaration is a compile-time thing. It will cause compile-time errors, not crashes. You're invoking undefined behavior somehow but there is not sufficient code here to identify the problem.

Comment: `void init(HelloWorld* const & parent);` is an unusual declaration. Why the reference here?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you show here, other than the unsual passing of a pointer via `const&` and the illegal `_Background_` (which is an identifier reserved for the implementation - you should use a different include guard naming convention).

Comment: It's not clear from your question but is the `.h file` `Background.h` and the `.cpp file` `Background.cpp`? Perhaps your header is `HelloWorldScene.h` since the `.cpp file` is including it. Also, can you provide the code that uses the class?